# Error using ==> plot Vectors must be the same lengths

Tags: matlab

So I have the following two functions:

```
delta_t=T/N_time; 
delta_x=1/N_space; 
rho=delta_t/delta_x^2;
phi=zeros(N_space+1,N_time+1);
phi(:,1)=initial_condition((0:N_space)*delta_x);
for j=1:N_time;
    for i=2:N_space;
    phi(i,j+1)=rho*(phi(i-1,j)+phi(i+1,j))+(1-2*rho)*phi(i,j);
    end;
end;
phi = phi(end,:);
end
```

When I run my second function, I get this error:

Error using ==> plot Vectors must be the same lengths.

I don't know why the sizes are different. They should be the same since the second function calls the first function. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why did you change the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have your phi transposed somehow.  Your `x_var` is an `1 x (N_space + 1)` vector, your phi is `(N_space + 1) x (N_time + 1)` and you return `phi(end, :)`, which will be `1 x (N_time + 1)`.  Did you mean to return phi(:, end)?